# Unable to list all records from the table in PHP and MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
    require( '../connect_db.php' ) ;
    $query = $dbc->query('SELECT * FROM customer');
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['clientid'].' '.$row['inital'].' '.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].' '.$row['mobile'].' '.$row['landline'].' '.$row['email'].' '.$row['address'].' '.$row['postcode'].' '.$row['accessibility'];
    }
?>
```

but gives me a **Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch() in list_customer.php on line 13**

Comment: You appear to be confusing MySQLi with PDO here. Which is it you are using? The error message suggests MySQLi...

Comment: **MySQLi** is what i want to use but there is no clear article in the manual that explains how to do it I'm so confused but thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mysqli doesn't have method fetch, you probably meant fetch_assoc()

Comment: Firstly thanks for taking the time to reply Marko, So does this mean i change the code to this `while($row = $query->fetch_all(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {`

Comment: @KP2012 No, you need to use `$query->fetch_assoc()` on a MySQLi result resource.  `fetchAll()` is a PDO method. Just change to `while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc())`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks :) now just need to find a way to style it.

Comment: @KP2012 No, `mysql_result()` is part of a different API entirely. The way you are doing it is fine. Use the array keys rather than placing values in global variables.  Or you can store all rows onto a 2D array then loop over that to create your table. Don't make a mess with global variables.

Comment: Build an array of all rows: `$rows = array(); while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) { $rows[] = $row; }` Then later `foreach ($rows as $row) { // do stuff with $row['lastname'], etc }`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I really did want to ask you more but I'm not getting anywhere `<tr>
<?php
 $query = $dbc->query('SELECT * FROM customer');
        $rows = array(); while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['clientid'].' '.$row['inital'].' '.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].' '.$row['mobile'];
        }
foreach ($rows as $row) { 
?>
 <td><?php echo $row['clientid']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['inital']; ?></td> 
 <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['mobile']; ?></td>
 <?php } ?>
</tr>`

Comment: @KP2012 You should ask a new question if you need more help, as this doesn't belong in a comment thread, but what you're missing from my quick example is the part where fetched rows get appended on to the array in the while loop: `$rows[] = $row;` Don't `echo` anything in the while loop, just build up the `$rows` array then do all your output in the `foreach` later.

Answer (score 0):

A glance at [the documentation for the mysqli_result class](http://php.net/mysqli_result) confirms that there is indeed no such method as `fetch` on that class.

See that page for the methods that are available.