# foreach ($rows as $row) cannot add html tags

Tags: php, mysqli

following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915573/unable-to-list-all-records-from-the-table-in-php-and-mysqli/14915589#14915589) now i need to style the output only to find that php does not like my way of putting tags I also tried to encapsulate it in `"` and the `.` or `<?php $row['field'] ?>` but still did not work.

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
<caption>List All Customers from Customer Table</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>Inital</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Mobile</th>
<th>Landline</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Post Code</th>
</tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php
foreach ($rows as $row) { 
?>
 <td><?php $row['clientid']; ?></td>
 <td><?php $row['inital']; ?></td> 
 <td><?php $row['firstname']; ?></td>
 <td><?php $row['lastname']; ?></td>
 <td><?php $row['mobile']; ?></td>
 <td><?php $row['landline']; ?></td>
 <td><?php $row['email']; ?></td>
 <td><?php $row['address']; ?></td>
 <td><?php $row['postcode']; ?></td>
 <?php } ?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

It does not work, shows no result. :( Pulling hairs out! Looked at alternative questions but northing clear enough.

Comment: Just write `echo` before the variables.

Comment: `<tbody>
<tr>
<?php
 $query = $dbc->query('SELECT * FROM customer');
        $rows = array(); while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['clientid'].' '.$row['inital'].' '.$row['firstname'];
        }
foreach ($rows as $row) { 
?>
 <td><?php echo $row['clientid']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['inital']; ?></td> 
 <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
 <?php } ?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>` still does not work

Comment: You're defining $rows as an empty array.... so why do you expect something to be displayed when you echo it?

Comment: @MarkBaker I already told it that I want it to pull the data from the customers table by this `$query = $dbc->query('SELECT * FROM customer');
        $rows = array(); while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['clientid'].' '.$row['inital'].' '.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].' '.$row['mobile'].' '.$row['landline'].' '.$row['email'].' '.$row['address'].' '.$row['postcode'].' '.$row['accessibility'];
        }` which works well on its own but when i add `foreach` it does not work

Comment: I repeat what I said: $rows is an empty array because you're saying `$rows = array();` to create it as an empty array.... your code doesn't store anything in that array, so it remains empty. $rows isn't automagically populated with data just because you have a variable called $row as well

Answer (score 5):

add `echo`..

```
<td><?php echo $row['clientid']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['inital']; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['mobile']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['landline']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['postcode']; ?></td>
```

Comment: then there must be a problem with your connection to database.. try `print_r($row)` if it shows anything

Comment: database connection works correctly, already checked and checked again. As without `foreach` bit it does show all records in an unformatted block one after the other in a continuous sentence so not a database connection problem.

Comment: As Mark Baker stated, your variable `$rows` is empty. Use that `while` loop you used to fetch results, instead of `foreach`.

`<?php $query = $dbc->query('SELECT * FROM customer'); while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) { echo $row['clientid'].' '.$row['inital'].' '.$row['firstname']; }`

Comment: well I used the code that you said was working, so I'm really out of ideas

Comment: does it give you an error? Did you try printing `$query` and `$row`?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to edit your code from your comment:
Probably you just did not push values into $rows array.

```
<?php 
 $rows = array() ;
 $result = $dbc->query('SELECT * FROM customer');
 if ($result){
   while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $rows[] = $row ; //Put your data in the array first. 
   }
 }
?>

<table>
<tbody> 
 <tr> 
<?php 
 foreach ($rows as $row) { ?> 
  <td><?php echo $row['clientid']; ?></td> 
  <td><?php echo $row['inital']; ?></td> 
  <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td> 
<?php } ?> 
 </tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>
```